# Execute shell process in new buffer/pane or silently within Vim

Tags: shell, vim, neovim

I'm looking to execute a shell process that doesn't execute unless the user does so. For example `gulp watch`, `htop`, `tail -f /path/to/some/log.log`, etc. All these processes execute until the user says otherwise. I'm looking for a way to execute a shell command and one of a couple options:

1. Open a new buffer with the running process
2. Open a new pane with the running process
3. Silently execute the shell command and ignore all output (output to `/dev/null`)

I understand there's a `gulp` vim plugin that gives the ability to run gulp processes, but I'm looking for a generic way to execute any shell command and run it in one of the listed fashions.

Comment: Why don't you simply do that in another terminal? Vim is a text editor, not a desktop environment.

Comment: I could easily do these tasks in another terminal, but I personally prefer to use vim/neovim to go beyond and remove me from having to navigate more windows/tabs in my terminal. After letting this sit in my head for a bit, I could have neovim open a new buffer with a term emulator instance and execute the command... looking into this option

Comment: tpope's [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch) plugin.